# Determine the pairs of integers $(x,y)$ that verify the relation: $x^2y^2+2xy+36=3y^2+8x^2$

Tags: relations, integers

**the question**

Determine the pairs of integers $(x,y)$ that verify the relation:

$$x^2y^2+2xy+36=3y^2+8x^2$$

**the idea**

Fist of all I tried getting everything on the LHS and write it as a product of numbers or a sum of perfect squares that equal 0, but got to nothing useful.

Then I tried writing everything as $(xy+1)^2=3y^2+8x^2-35$ or as $(x^2-2)(y^2-7)+22=(x-y)^2$, but again you can see we can do nothing with these.

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Brute forcing all integers $|x|, |y| \le 100$ gives $(x, y) \in \{(-3, -2), (-3, 3), (-2, 2), (2, -2), (3, -3), (3, 2)\}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde How did you got that $x|3(y^2-12)$ and how are these divisibilities going to help us.

Comment: Potential hint: You can use the Quadratic Formula to solve for $y$, giving $y = \frac{-x \pm \sqrt{8 x^4 - 59 x^2 + 108}}{x^2 - 3}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for the idea. I tried processing the second case when $x|y^2-12$ but May i ask how to find the other pairs?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I do not get your conclusion that if $x\mid 3(y^2-12)$ then $x=\pm 3$, or $x\mid y^2-12$, this would require $3$ and $y^2-12$ to be coprime. Take $y=6$ and $x=9$, then $x\mid 3(y^2-12)$ but $x \nmid y^2-12$.

Comment: Following up on @Dan, $8x^4-59x^2+108$ is not a square for any $3 < |x| < 10^9$.

Comment: Building on my previous comment I do not think that there are any additional solutions since we need $|x|\leq 3$ or $|x| \geq 10^{400000}$.

Comment: @jorisperrenet Take prime divisors of $x$. Then $p\mid 3b$ implies $p=3$ or $p\mid b$.

Comment: Expressing $y$ locally as a function of $x$, one sees that $y \to \pm \sqrt 8 \approx \pm 2.82$ as $\left| x\right| \to \infty$ (by the formula given by @Dan), so it can only hit finitely many integers. By studying its monotonicity, one should be able to give an explicit bound for the last time it crosses $2$ or $3$ (resp. $-2$ or $-3$). This is a slightly more gnarly calculation than I feel like doing right now, but if someone wants to write it up, then go ahead.

Comment: Maybe you are no longer interested in this question, but there is a very simple solution. Try to prove that if $|x|\ge 3$ and $|y|\ge 4$, then $(x^2-3)(y^2-8)+2xy+12=0$ has no integer solutions. Then, you have only $|x|\lt 3$ or $|y|\lt 4$ to check. In this solution, you don't have to do a lot of calculations. I guess there might be other simple solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution based on different ideas from the comments. Let us solve this equation for $y$, we get $$y=\frac{-x+ \sqrt{8x^4-59x^2+108}}{x^2-3},\tag1$$ $$y=\frac{-x- \sqrt{8x^4-59x^2+108}}{x^2-3}.\tag2$$

Let us prove that if $|x|>3$ then $y$ in the form $(1)$ is in $(2,3)$: $$2<\frac{-x+ \sqrt{8x^4-59x^2+108}}{x^2-3}<3.$$

Multiply by $x^2-3>0$: $$2x^2-6+x<\sqrt{8x^4-59x^2+108}<3x^2-9+x.$$

Square all sides (they are positive while $|x|>3$): $$4x^4+36+x^2-24x^2-12x+4x^3<8x^4-59x^2+108<$$ $$<9x^4+81+x^2-54x^2+6x^3-18x.$$

Left inequality is: $$4x^4-4x^3-36x^2+12x+72>0$$
$$\iff x^4-x^3-9x^2+3x+18>0$$
$$\iff (x+2)(x-3)(x^2-3)>0,$$

which is true for $|x|>3$. The right inequality is:

$$x^4+6x^3+6x^2-18x-27>0$$
$$\iff (x+3)^2(x^2-3)>0,$$

which is again true for $|x|>3$.

Now prove the similar statement for $y$ in the form $(2)$: $$|x|>3\implies -2>\frac{-x- \sqrt{8x^4-59x^2+108}}{x^2-3}>-3.$$

Multiply by $x^2-3>0$: $$-2x^2+6+x>-\sqrt{8x^4-59x^2+108}>-3x^2+9+x$$

$$\iff 2x^2-6-x<\sqrt{8x^4-59x^2+108}<3x^2-9+x$$

Square all sides (they are positive while $|x|>3$): $$4x^4+36+x^2-24x^2+12x-4x^3<8x^4-59x^2+108<$$ $$<9x^4+81+x^2-54x^2-6x^3+18x.$$

Left inequality is: $$4x^4+4x^3-36x^2-12x+72>0$$
$$\iff x^4+x^3-9x^2-3x+18>0$$
$$\iff (x-2)(x+3)(x^2-3)>0,$$

which is true for $|x|>3$. The right inequality is:

$$x^4-6x^3+6x^2+18x-27>0$$
$$\iff (x-3)^2(x^2-3)>0,$$

which is again true for $|x|>3$.

Now we could do the same thing solving the initial equation for $x$ and repeating the similar reasoning showing that $|y|$ can’t be more than $2\sqrt2$. Or we can just solve seven linear/quadratic equations putting $x=-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$ in the initial equation and getting all the solutions: $(-3,-2),(-3,3),(-2,2),(2,-2),(3,-3),(3,2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea. May is sk if I understood correctly. So you say that y cant take any integer value when $|x|>3$ in any of the 2 forms, which means that $x=-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$ and verify them??

Comment: Yes, look at the [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x2y2%2B2xy-3y2-8x2%2B36%3D0%2C+x%3D3..10), when $|x|>3$ then the upper branch is between $y=2$ and $y=3$, and the lower is between $y=-2$ and $y=-3$. It can’t be integer there. So we just have to try small values of $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Grouping the terms of $y$ gives
$$(x^2-3)y^2 + (2x)y + (36-8x^2).$$
The quadratic formula implies (just as @Dan suggested) that
$$y = \frac{-x\pm \sqrt{8x^4-59x^2+108}}{x^2-3}.$$
Since we require $y$ to be integer we need $8x^4-59x^2+108$ to be a square.

Substituting $u=x^2$ we can look for $u$ such that $8u^2-59u+108$ is a square.
The Diophantine equation $8u^2-59u+109=w^2$ for some integer $w$ admits the following recurrence relation for $u$:
$u_0 = 4$, $u_1=9$, $u_2=184$, $u_n=u_{n-3}-35u_{n-2}+35u_{n-1}$.
Where $u_0, u_1, \dots$ represent all possible solutions for $u$ to the Diophantine equation.

Using that recurrence we can easily see that any $x$ satisfying the original equation must satisfy $x=\pm 2$, $x=\pm 3$, or $|x| > 10^3$ (note that you must check all solutions of $u$ up to $10^6$ to verify this, luckily there are only $5$ of these).

If $|x| > 10^3$ then $|y|<3$ (due to the comment of @sbares, we know that this bound holds as $x$ get large).

We thus have $x = \pm 2$, $x = \pm 3$, or $y\in \{ 0, \pm 1, \pm 2 \}$.
Substituting these values in the original equation gives the solutions
$(x, y) \in {(−3,−2),(−3,3),(−2,2),(2,−2),(3,−3),(3,2)}$. (As @Dan computed earlier on).

Comment: Note: the bound of $10^3$ was arbitrary, a much smaller bound would also have sufficed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Is there any way to explain this without using The Diophantine equation or functions(I haven't learned them yet)?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU, looks like I don't need to anymore.